# File system project "Member access into incomplete type" error

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am working on a file management system project on c++ but I'm stuck right now.

Let me picture the scenario:

I have a `DataObject` class that will be the parent for the other ones I am going to create (like directory or file). Inside such `DataObject` class I define some dates and parameters. The problem comes when I declare its child classes (`File` and `Directory`) since I got errors when I try to retrieve information of the class that is declared below... I've already defined that is going to be 3 classes (`DataObject`, `Directory` and `File`) on the top of the program so the compiler knows the existence of these classes.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Directory;
class DataObject;
class File;

time_t now;

class DataObject
{
private:
    string date_created;
    string last_time_accessed;
    string last_updated;
    string name;
    DataObject* parent;
public:
    DataObject(string n, DataObject * p)
    {
        date_created=ctime(&now);
        last_time_accessed=ctime(&now);
        last_updated=ctime(&now);
        name=n;
        parent=p;
    }
    DataObject* getParent() {return parent;}
    string getName() {return name;}
    string getFullPath()
    {
        if(getParent()==NULL) return getName();
        else return getParent()->getFullPath()+"/"+getName();
    }
};

class Directory : public DataObject
{
private:
    list<File*> contents;
public:
    Directory(string n, Directory * p) : DataObject(n,p) {}
    void addDataObject(File & f)
    {
        contents.push_back(&f);
    }
    int size()
    {
        int size=0;
        for(File* c: contents)
        {
            size+=c->getSize(); //error on this line: "Member access to incomplete type "File"
        }
        return size;
    }
    void displayContents()
    {
        list<File*>::iterator myList;
        int i=1;
        for(myList=contents.begin();myList!=contents.end();myList++)
        {
            File* aux=*myList;
            cout<<i<<" - "<<aux->getName()<<endl; // Error here: Member access to incomplete type "File"
        }
    }

};

class File : public DataObject
{
private:
    int size;
    string content="default";
    friend class Directory;
public:
    File(string n, Directory* p,int s) : DataObject(n,p),size(s)
    {
        p->addDataObject(*this);
    }
    int getSize() {return size;}
    string getContent() {return content;}
    void setContent(string c) {content=c;}
};
```

Could you please give me a suggestion to get rid of this error? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: you dont need to inline your function definitions in class declarations; just write them below, where your File class is already declared.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong please. I just removed the:
class Directory;
class DataObject;
class File;
Lines. But now another error has popped "Unkown type name 'File'... Did you refer to another thing?

Comment: Of course it's "unknown type name", you just removed it! Why would you do that? I only meant to move your function body Directory::size() below the File class definition, what else could it be?

Comment: Very clever Sir... very, very Clever... Thanks a lot! I didn't catch what you said. Now the error is gone

Answer (score 2):

At the point where this occurs:

```
size+=c->getSize();
```

You only have a forward-declaration of `File` -- which is fine as long as all you need is a pointer-to-`File`, but as soon as you need to call a method on `File` the compiler needs to know what the heck a `File` is.

The definition came just after this function.  All you need to do it move the definition of `File` to before you try to use it in this manner.  In fact, it doesn't look like you need a forward-declare at all in this particular example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I followed your instructions, but unfortunately If I do so, now the error pops for the File class, since it uses a Directory pointer inside of it... As summary, File uses Directory and Directory uses File... is there any way to let the compiler knows the existence of both classes?

Comment: Ah, you likely have a circular dependancy.  You'll need to break that.  You design is broken.